# How to chart a count of value occurences spanning multiple columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a set of columns in Excel that contain various values. In the example image below, there are two but there can be any number of columns (I can predict a max -- say out to Column Z). I'd like to turn this data into a bar chart with the horizontal axis indicating the value and the vertical axis indicating the total count of those occurences, EXCLUDING EMPTY VALUES. So the actual data set for this would look like this (the "Custom Field" values are the header values in Row 1 which need to be excluded):

- EOI: 1
- Research: 2
- Incorrect Data Generated: 1
- Cleanup: 1

I'm not a very advanced Excel user and I've been experimenting with pivot tables, etc. but I can't quite get things set right.

[image: Excel fields]

Answer (score 0):

*Yes it's possible that you can swap X & Y axis. For this you need to follow below written steps.*

1. Click anywhere on the chart.
2. You find 3 Tabs at the top of the screen,
   **Design**, **Layout** & **Format**.
3. Hit the **Design tab**.
4. Find the button **Switch Row/Column**.
5. Finally click it.

*Hope this help you.*